# How to remove string between two string including both start string as well end string?

Tags: c#, .net

Example string :

```
"< harshal bhamare > sfjkgdbgfbguifg < fbgfg >";
```

I want to remove  total string `"< harshal bhamare >"` which is starts with 
`"<"` and ends with `">"`.

Comment: You forgot to post the code you have tried.

Comment: Do you wanna remove `< fbgfg >` part since it starts with `<` and ends with `>` as well? Or you wanna remove _only_ first sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```
<.*?>(.*)<.*?>
```

It removes everything inside the brackets including the brackets itself (the `?` makes it non-greedy, so `<` and `>` inside the text block is allowed), and captures the text in between. You can get that out by getting the first capture, like in this C# code:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"<.*>(.*)<.*>", "$1");
```

Comment: I suggest use `(<.+?>)` pattern and instead replace by empty string. Because input may be something like `<abc> abc <abc> abc` and your pattern does not work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to use the regex solution you could simply iterate over each character and watch for start/end characters, omitting those within.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool skip = false;
foreach (char c in "< harshal bhamare > sfjkgdbgfbguifg < fbgfg >")
{
    if (c.Equals('<')) skip = true;
    if (c.Equals('>')) { skip = false; continue; }

    if (!skip) sb.Append(c);

}

System.Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```